# Можно ли сделать рассылку через Telegram API на Java (Не бот)

Tags: java, telegram

Допустим у меня есть канал в телеграме, я хочу с помощью Telegram API получать список читателей с их контактами и потом делать рассылку для отдельных пользователей. Но это не должен быть бот, т.к. бот не может писать первым. Также хотел реализовать приглашение пользователей с помощью апи.
Я просмотрел документацию, но не смог найти примеры того, как должна выглядеть строка запроса для каждого из предоставленных методов, чтобы протестировать запрос хотя бы через Postman. Кто-нибудь уже делал что-то подобное, где брать примеры запросов? Куда смотреть?
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Можешь зайти в телегу через десктопный браузер, нажать на F12 (инстременты разработчика) и перейти во вкладку Network, там у тебя будут отображены запросы (Headers -> General -> request url - адрес куда посылаются запросы, для POST запроса в Headers ->request payload - тело запроса)
Так же, для удобства можешь поставить галочку Preserve log - чтобы при обновлении страницы не очищались логи в network.
И удачи тебе в декодировании информации))

Comment: @Ruslan Спасибо, буду пробовать)